# jQuery send data AJAX after the time is up

Tags: php, jquery, html

So, I have a form that has to be filled by the user in a duration. (Fyi, it's still a dummy web). Let's say the duration is 100sec. After 100sec, the data should be sent to database. Here are my codes :

**HTML**

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
<form class="test" method="post">
<?php
    for($num=1;$num<=10;$num++){
      echo "<div class=\"question\">" .$num. "<br>"; /* the question is written here */
      echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"answer" .$num. "\" value=\"A\">A<br>";
      echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"answer" .$num. "\" value=\"B\">B<br>";
      echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"answer" .$num. "\" value=\"C\">C<br>";
    }
?>
</form>
```

Why did I do PHP and looping? Coz this is the prototype of my form and also for shortening purpose. I'll not do this for the real web. But, if you think this is a bad idea although it's just a dummy web, just tell me :)

**jQuery**

```
var duration=100;
var countdown=setInterval(timer,1000);

function timer(){
  duration=duration-1;
  $("#countdown").html(duration+" sec");
  if(duration<=0){
    clearInterval(countdown);
    var form_data=$(".test").serialize();

    $.post("action.php",form_data,function(){alert("success!")});
  }
}
```

**action.php**

```
<?php
  include("connection.php"); /* it's the connection to the database */

  $answer1=$_POST["answer1"];
  $answer2=$_POST["answer2"];
  $answer3=$_POST["answer3"];
  $answer4=$_POST["answer4"];
  $answer5=$_POST["answer5"];
  $answer6=$_POST["answer6"];
  $answer7=$_POST["answer7"];
  $answer8=$_POST["answer8"];
  $answer9=$_POST["answer9"];
  $answer10=$_POST["answer10"];

mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO prototype (`answer1`,`answer2`,`answer3`,`answer4`,`answer5`,`answer6`,`answer7`,`answer8`,`answer9`,`answer10`) VALUES ('$answer1','$answer2','$answer3','$answer4','$answer5','$answer6','$answer7','$answer8','$answer9','$answer10')";
?>
```

So, the problem is : after the duration = 0, the success action (alert) appears, but after I checked the database, no data has been stored. Wut's actually happen?

Comment: You're inserting `'$j1','$j2' ...` but have `$answer1, $answer2 ...`

Comment: Yup. Thats the answer ^

Comment: Actually, j1, j2, etc are the real variable in my files. I forget to convert it into $answer :p

Comment: I've edited and coverted it, please help me to fix the ajax problem :)

Comment: Put your sql into variable ($sql) and do a `var_dump($sql)`, or `echo` it out. Copy paste it and manually insert it through your dbm workbench. If it doesn't work, then you should get an error. You might also be able to see the error by looking at the sql directly, i.e. if any variables are empty etc. You're also not closing your `mysqli_query` function.

Comment: you probably have a PHP syntax error, unless that's just a typo in your version here. Take a look at your browser's console and see if you have any errors, also look at the response generated by the ajax call (via your browser's Network tool)

Comment: P.S. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.